# Python package to estimate Perron-Frobenius Eigenvalue of real, square, non-negative matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

Is there an optimized package or method that estimates the Perron-Frobenius eigenvalue of a real, square, non-negative matrix?  This could be significantly faster (especially for large and/or sparse matrices) than an exact calculation -- given that the Perron-Frobenius eigenvalue can be arrived at by iterating the matrix.  I am hoping an optimized package exists which does this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `A` is a square matrix, possibly in a sparse format, then you can get its largest magnitude (LM) eigenvalue, i.e. its Perron-Frobenius eigenvalue, and the corresponding eigenvector using SciPy’s [`eigs`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs.html) and [`eigsh`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.eigsh.html) functions:

```py
from scipy.sparse.linalg import eigs

val, vec = eigs(a, k=1, which='LM')
```

SciPy has [solvers for sparse eigenvalue problems](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.linalg.html#matrix-factorizations) of various forms that use the ARPACK library. You can read more in [SciPy’s ARPACK tutorial](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/tutorial/arpack.html).

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I wanted. Missed the 'which' flag. Also, it's interesting (and great) that this should be in the sparse package. Double points.